# How to clean out a contaminated aluminum automotive radiator

Tags: solutions

I have a very expensive custom made automotive aluminum radiator that has had a mouse or mice nesting inside the top tank.  I have removed most of the nesting material through the top inlet but I want to clear the radiator tubes that may be plugged up with the nesting material (looks like cotton of some sort) and be sure the radiator is flowing water through it as it should. As it is an aluminum radiator I am told they cannot remove the tank and "rod out" the radiator tubes.  The only solution offered by the company is replacement.  The radiator cost about $1200.

I have thought about an enzymatic drain cleaner but am not sure that it will not harm the aluminum radiator internally.  What ideas do you have?

Comment: I think an enzymatic cleaner should be OK. DO NOT USE DRAIN CLEANER or anything based on hydroxides.

Answer (score -1):

Well I actually tried a small jar of the Enzymatic product with a sample of the nesting material I already removed as well as small piece of .023 6061 aluminum... Overnight the aluminum was completely decomposed.  The nesting material seemed unfazed.  So much for that idea!